# Get Initials of First Name C# XAML through Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a name such as Jonny Bravo, and I would like my label to reflect the initials of that name (JB) through Binding. How can I?

I need a code entirely through XAML/Binding and possible ValueConverter if needed. Any suggestions?

Comment: put a property in your ViewModel, as a quick solution, otherwise implement a converter. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ValueConverter.

Converter:

```
public class InitialsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string s = value as string;
        string i = string.Empty;

        if (s != null)
        {
            string[] split = s.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach (string piece in split)
            {
                i += piece[0];
            }
        }

        return i;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Xaml use:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource InitialsConverter}}" />
```

Comment: I have a one property for the Name and one for the Initials. And I want to Initials to update automatically based on the Initials of the Name field. Can you post some examples?

Comment: It would probably easier to just have a converter for where you want to display the initials, that way you wouldn't need to have another property.

Comment: yes, i was thinking that. do you have any code examples to that effect?

Comment: i edited the answer to show one possible way for the converter to work.  you may want to think about some additional logic, because names with ie. III or , Jr. will not work correctly though.  It will work for First, Middle, Last etc. though as is

Comment: your code works, but only brings the first name for some reason. any ideas why? because in your code i can clearly see it splittling words.

Comment: did you make a typo?  it works fine for me, i get "JB" when the name is Johnny Bravo.  I also get "JAB" if the name is Johnny Alpha Bravo...put a breakpoint inside the converter and step through to make sure A) you are passing the whole name to the converter and b) that "i" is getting assigned each initial...

Comment: <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=lblContact, Path=Content, Converter={StaticResource InitialsConverter}}"/>

Comment: Why are you binding it to another element?  just bind it to whatever your name property is

Comment: does that really matter though? I just did it to test it out in design time quickly.

Comment: i did it the way you are doing it, it still works fine.  something is either wrong with the binding of that element, the property itself or you have a typo or something in the converter i gave you

Comment: typo in the code for iValueConverter. Fixed and Done!! Thank you good sir.

Answer (score 0):

Fill the Initials Property inside the Setter of the FullName Property at your viewModel

```
Public string FullName{
...
Set{
this.fullName = value;
this.Initials = GenerateInitialsFromFullName();
}
```

Or create an ValueConverter as already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Using a value converter would be the way to go because it's reusable in other places in your code if needed.

Here's a quick one I threw together using Regex to find the first letters (note that splitting the string would offer better performance).

```
public class InitialsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public virtual object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string str = value as string;
        if (str != null)
        {
            string s = "";
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"(\b\w)");
            foreach (Match m in matches)
                s += m.Value;
            return s;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public virtual object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<!--Declare in your scope's resources-->
<Window.Resources>
    <r:InitialsConverter x:Key="initials"/>
</Window.Resources>

<!--Bind to a string using the converter-->
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyName, Converter={StaticResource initials}}"/>
```

No converter:

[image]

Using converter:

[image]

Comment: both work, but I only get the first letter for some reason. I am using a label, and point to that label within the same window. any ideas?

Comment: Chuck a break point in the `InitialsConverter.Convert` method and step through -- you may be able to work out what's wrong this way.